# Use of google Analytics SDK 3.09 needs to check Advertising Identifier(IDFA) in iTunes Connect?

Tags: google-analytics, app-store-connect, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I used Google Analytics SDK 3.09 in my app and wants to submit the app to appstore but am bit confused whether i need to check Advertising Identifier(IDFA) and its subsequent options for serving ads and more. Am not showing any ads in app just using GAITracker to track the home screen do i still need to check IDFA? Please guide me more on this i googled but did not get great help on this.

Comment: did you figure anything out?  I'm currently in the same situation.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: yes. my app did not have any problem with these settings. you can upload your app if you have same situation.

Answer (score 2):

IDFA is disabled by default. If you need IDFA (for example for campaign tracking of installs), you need to link appropriate files and then enable it explicitly, like so:

```
// Enable IDFA collection.
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

[See GA documentation for more details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#idfa)

So, by default, there's no need to mention that your app uses IDFA.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Google Analytics to track conversions for your app.IDFA (Identifier for Advertisers) requires for 'libAdIdAccess.a' and 'AdSupport.framework. So check the 2nd & 3rd option in IDFA -> "Attribute this app installation to a previously served ad". AND "Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement".